# how to write a wave file using scipy, if you are provided with sample rate and frequency values

Tags: scipy, wav

please help me with an example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SciPy, you can do this with Python using the [Wave module](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html?highlight=wave#wave-write-objects).